# Query Builder return null for join result and raw query in AdonisJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js, adonis.js

I want to get **count** result by **Database.raw** in a **select** query of the query builder but when my main table is empty, all fields of my query are `null` except **Database.raw** result.

Here is my query:

```
const jobs = await Database.table('jobs')
  .leftJoin('job_offers', 'jobs.id', 'job_offers.job_id')
  .select([
    Database.raw(`'job' as type`),
    Database.raw('COUNT(jobs.id) as offers_count'),
    'jobs.id', 'title', 'jobs.description', 'jobs.created_at',
  ])
  .limit(limit).offset(offset)
```

and my query result is:

```
[
    {
        "type": "job",
        "offers_count": 0,
        "id": null,
        "title": null,
        "description": null,
        "created_at": null
    }
]
```

In the above query, the result must be `[]` when there are not any row in my `job` table.

**Update:**

Here is the SQL command of above query builder methods, that return `[]` as result

```sql
SELECT 
    'job' AS type,
    jobs.id, jobs.title, description, jobs.created_at,
    COUNT(job_offers.id) as offers_count

    FROM jobs
LEFT JOIN job_offers ON jobs.id = job_offers.id
```

What is wrong in my query?

Answer (score -2):

You are using leftJoin, if you don't want null results you should use innerJoin or join (both do the same thing).

```html
const jobs = await Database.table('jobs')
  .join('job_offers', 'jobs.id', 'job_offers.job_id')
  .select([
    Database.raw(`'job' as type`),
    Database.raw('COUNT(jobs.id) as offers_count'),
    'jobs.id', 'title', 'jobs.description', 'jobs.created_at',
  ])
  .limit(limit).offset(offset)
```

Comment: Great answer, but providing example code would help users understand it better